# Unable to locate bitcoin.conf in linux

Tags: bitcoind, regtest, bitcoin.conf

I am new to bitcoin network but I have spent significant time with ethereum. 
For getting started with bitcoin I referred [running a full node](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#linux-instructions) and [Developer documentation- Regtest Mode](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode). After installing `bitcoin-qt` and `bitcoind`, I was asked to change the password in `bitcoin.conf`. But I am unable to locate it in `~/<user>/.bitcoin`.

```
pr.singh@GLTINTERN-W040:~/.bitcoin$ ls
bitcoind.pid  blocks  chainstate  database  db.log  debug.log  regtest  wallet.dat
```

And so whenever I run any command like `bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 101`, I get error stating:

> error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and no rpcpassword is set in the configuration file (/home/pr.singh/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)

Am I missing anything? Also if you guys can provide a good tutorial to start development and  testing in `restest network`, it will be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You showed a directory listig using "ls". Maybe that is the first issue. Try using "ls -la", which would also show hidden folders, beginning with a dot.

Otherwise here is a tutorial:
https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode
and
https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#linux-instructions

difficult to say, what happened, but if you just create a ".bitcoin" directory, and go ahead to create the bitcoin.conf file, you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks. I was following the exact same tutorials. I have created bitcoin.conf file myself, but I think it's a workaround. It should be generated automatically.